# C# Cannot await in the body of a catch clause

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I just downloaded some code from codeproject.com and have come across this error.
here's the code:

```
catch (WebException webEx)
        {
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)webEx.Response;

            //Re-fetching token
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized ||
                response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.NotFound) throw;
            Debug.Print(webEx.Message);
            Token.Cookie = "";
            Token.Crumb = "";
            Debug.Print("Re-fetch token");
            return await GetRawAsync(symbol, start, end).ConfigureAwait(false);// Cannot await in the body of a catch clause
        }
```

Please help with a fix since I've never used try and catch before.
Thanks.

Comment: Newer versions of C# no longer have this restriction. You'll have to upgrade to a newer VS version if you want to use `await` in a `catch` clause. The Community editions of VS 2015 and 2017 are free and provide the same functionality as VS Professional

Comment: Oh, I have VS2015 installed also. I'll try. Thanks.

Comment: Build successful. Works great!